# Unable to edit body field

Tags: users

One of my content editors reported having trouble editing

[image]

However, I have allowed this group to edit any content of this node type.

[image]

I'm not seeing any separate permissions for fields. How might I over come this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You also need to grant permissions for the text format that the body field is using, e.g.

[image]